# Trying to setup a filter by changing classNames based on what filter is selected, for some reason unable to remove the classname

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically what I am trying to do here is follow this:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_elements

so I setup my FilterNow component as seen here:

```
function FilterNow() {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="section section-signup"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          top: "-300px",
          marginBottom: "-300px",
        }}
      >
        <Container>
          <div id="myBtnContainer">
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('all')" className="btn active">
              View All
            </Button>
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('Trulive')" className="btn">
              {" "}
              Trulieve
            </Button>
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('Harvest')" className="btn">
              {" "}
              Harvest
            </Button>
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('Rise')" className="btn">
              {" "}
              Rise
            </Button>
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('ColumbiaCare')" className="btn">
              {" "}
              Columbia Care
            </Button>
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('Muv')" className="btn">
              {" "}
              Muv
            </Button>
            <br />
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('Curaleaf')" className="btn">
              {" "}
              Curaleaf
            </Button>
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('VidaCann')" className="btn">
              {" "}
              VidaCann
            </Button>
            <Button
              onclick="filterSelection('LibertyHealthSciences')"
              className="btn"
            >
              {" "}
              Libery Health Sciences
            </Button>
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('Fluent')" className="btn">
              {" "}
              Fluent
            </Button>
            <Button onclick="filterSelection('OnePlant')" className="btn">
              {" "}
              Oneplant
            </Button>
            <Button
              onclick="filterSelection('SurterraWelness')"
              className="btn"
            >
              {" "}
              Surterra Welness
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default FilterNow;
```

and that is where I added all the buttons and the onClick filter selections for you to be able to swap between filter selections. Then I setup my react component which has props passed into it to setup the classname for the component to be "filterDIV " + the prop which is the dispensary name "Trulieve, Harvest, etc as examples" that way the filterSelection on the buttons know which it is.

```
    <div className={"filterDiv " + props.DealDisp}>
          <Container>
            <Col>
              <div className="cardControl">
                <Card>
                  <br />
                  <CardHeader>
                    <span id="DealName">{props.DealName}</span>
                  </CardHeader>
                  <CardBody>
                    <TabContent className="text-center">
                      <p id="DealDesc">{props.DealDesc}</p>
                      <p id="DealDisp">{props.DealDisp}</p>
                      <div id="timer">
                        <p id="time">{props.DealEnd}</p>
                      </div>
                    </TabContent>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Container>
        </div>
```

and then last I setup the javascript here:

```
function FilterHelp() {
  filterSelection("all");
  function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
    if (c == "all") c = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
      if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
  }

  function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
        element.className += " " + arr2[i];
      }
    }
  }

  function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
        arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
      }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
  }

  // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
  var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
  var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      this.className += " active";
    });
  }
}
```

I also have all the proper CSS in place CSS is not the issue here anyways.

Now basically everything is almost working perfectly but I am running into issues with 1 thing. So right now each component has the correct className it should, "show" is adding to it as it should and the components show up after a few seconds when show is added to them so that part is working perfect. My issue here is when toggling between selected buttons, show is not being removed from the classNames like its being added in. Leading me to believe there is possibly an issue somewhere in my code here

```
  function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
        arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
      }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
  }
```

which is where that should be removed from the class based on which button is clicked.

If anyone can spot how I am messing up here, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Bad news for you: w3schools have some very bad stuff on it. And this code is one of them

Comment: I had it working previously but its a long story and I forgot to backup this part so im back at phase 1 and cant see what im doing wrong this time around lmao.

Comment: `onclick="filterSelection('Liberty Health Sciences')"` wont work.. you can't have spaces

Comment: yeah I already fixed that when I noticed it ill edit. thats not the issue here tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This w3school example is for regular HTML. With React you can do it in a much easier way using map.

```
// Create an array of things to display
const containers = [
  {name:'BMW', filter:'cars'},
  {name:'Orange', filter:'colors'},
  ...
]
// Then in your render function use props.filter to display what you want
containers.map((container, index) => {
  if (props.filter && props.filter !== container.filter) return null;
  return <div key={index}>{container.name}</div>
});
```

Comment: I forgot the key in the div generated by map, I have just updated my code

Answer (score 1):

When this code was written (some 20 years ago) there were no [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property, which makes things much simpler:

```
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  element.classList.add(name);
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  element.classList.remove(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The overall issue here is that you are mixing React and some vanilla (old-school style) JavaScript.

You should implement your filter using React state and React event handler (instead of the `onclick` attribute).

Here's how I would do it by having a parent component managing the state for both `FilterNow` component and your items list:

```js
// Defines the filters (I ommited some of them for the demo)
const FILTERS = [
  'Trulive',
  'Harvest',
  'Rise',
];
// Defines the items (I ommited most of the property for the demo)
const ITEMS = [
  {
    name: 'Deal 1',
    categories: ['Trulive'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Deal 2',
    categories: ['Harvest'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Deal 3',
    categories: ['Trulive', 'Harvest'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Deal 4',
    categories: ['Rise'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Deal 5',
    categories: ['Rise', 'Harvest'],
  },
];

// A Item component to display an item
function Item({ item }) {
  return (
    <div>{item.name}</div>
  );
}

// A Filter component to display a filter button
function Filter({ name, onClick, active }) {
  // If the `active` props is `true`, display the filter button as active.
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick} style={{ color: active ? 'red' : 'black' }}>{name}</button>
  );
}

function App() {
  // Store the current filter in the state (null by default, if all items should be displayed)
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState(null);
  // If `filter` is null, just use the ITEMS array as-is, otherwise filter only items of the array for which `categories` array includes the current filter
  const filteredItems = !filter ? ITEMS : ITEMS.filter(item => item.categories.includes(filter));
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Filters:
        <Filter name="All" onClick={() => setFilter()} active={!filter} />
        {/* Render a Filter component for each filter. Pass an `onClick` props that update the state with the new filter when clicked */}
        {FILTERS.map(filterName => (
          <Filter name={filterName} onClick={() => setFilter(filterName)} active={filterName === filter}/>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        Items:
        {filteredItems.map(item => (
          <Item item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, it's really simpler like this. All you have to do is filter your items array and only display the ones needed. React will handle all the re-rendering when your state is updated.